# Counting values of a dictionary in python where values are sets

Tags: python-3.x, set, list-comprehension

I have a file which contain test cases where first string of the line is name of the tribe and following string is name of the soldier. The soldiers can repeate along with their tribe names. I want to count them that how many men a specific tribe have. For that purpose I have made a dictionary with tribe name as key and a set as the value and for every soldier I am updating the set. The set is eliminating duplicate soldiers. In the end I want to count the values in the set, but for this purpose *I want to use list comprehesion*. What I am doing is counting them using a for loop. Here is the code.

```
f =  open("file.txt","r")
lines=f.readlines()

totalSOLDIERs=int(lines[0])
startOfCase=2
endOfCase=startOfCase+int(lines[startOfCase-1])

for X in range(totalSOLDIERs):
    rec=dict()
    for SOLDIER in lines[startOfCase:endOfCase]:
        KEY=SOLDIER.find(" ")
        if(SOLDIER[:KEY] not in rec.keys()):
            rec[SOLDIER[:KEY]]=set()
            rec[SOLDIER[:KEY]].add(SOLDIER[KEY:])
        else:
            rec[SOLDIER[:KEY]].add(SOLDIER[KEY:])
    print("Case: ", X+1)

    #this for loop is counting values in the set

    for Y in rec.keys():
        print(Y, len(rec[Y]))
    if(X==totalSOLDIERs-1):
        break
    startOfCase=endOfCase+1
    endOfCase=startOfCase+int(lines[startOfCase-1])
```

Secondly the algorithm and code can also be improved. can someone can help me out of this? I have also attached the snippet of the file. The first line contain test cases while the every test case has a count before it starts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are taking as input a list of liness where each line consists of two strings.  The first string is a **TribeName** and the Second string on the line is a **SoldierName**.
From this input you are creating a dict structure where the dict key= **TribeName** and the dict value is a set containing soldiers from the tribe.  You are using a set for this, since the **SoldierName** could repeat in you input list.  Once you have created the dict you would then like to count the nuber of soldiers associated with each tribe.
Assuming this is an accurate statement of your problem, this is how I would proceed:

```
# A simple list of input data for illustrative purposes
listOfCases = ['A Aa', 'B Ba', 'C Cd', 'B Bc', 'A Ab', 
               'C Ce', 'A Aa', 'B bb', 'C ce', 'B Bb']

# Process the cases defined by listOfCases
rslt = dict()  #Dictionary to store results
for l in listOfCases:
    c = l.split(' ')
    cset = rslt.pop(c[0], set())
    cset.add(c[1])
    rslt[c[0]] = cset
    
# Report Soldiers by Tribe
for k,v in rslt.items():
    print (f'Tribe: {k} has {len(v)} soldiers to include: {", ".join(list(v))}')
```

Produces the following output:

```
Tribe: A has 2 soldiers to include: Aa, Ab
Tribe: C has 3 soldiers to include: ce, Ce, Cd
Tribe: B has 4 soldiers to include: Bb, Bc, Ba, bb
```

Comment: You have understood the problem correctly but there can be more than one cases . Solution is also fine for one case only. I asked for list comprehension for counting soldiers  and again you used a loop.

Comment: For additional cases, put my code inside a loop for each case.

Comment: But I need list comprehension for counting soldiers

Comment: Why?  The number of soldiers is equal to the length of the set containing the soldiers, as I have shown in my code example.